# jquery on change event strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html

I m having a form to upload files using these tags

```
 <form id="uploadpic" action="../image_shout" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" multiple="true" id="File1" class="choose-file" name="choose-file"/>    
</form>
```

Now i want that on choosing a file a new file upload input should be inserted.

I tried that with jquery using the on change event handler using this code -

```
$('.choose-file').on("change", function(e) {               
    $(this).after("<input type=\"file\" multiple=\"true\" id=\"File1\" class=\"choose-file\" name=\"choose-file\" />");                
});
```

To my dismay this got bonded with only the first element of the input field. On choosing files on the subsequent inputs generated it does not add new input fields.

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/3jTrA/2/)

To get it to work i had to something much complicated -

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
function add_input($t) {        
    $t.after("<input type=\"file\" multiple=\"true\" id=\"File1\" class=\"choose-file\" name=\"choose-file\" />");        
    $('.choose-file').on("change", function(e) {
        var $t = $(this);        
        add_input($t);
    });        
}

$('.choose-file').on("change", function(e) {       
    var $t = $(this);        
    add_input($t);        
});   
});
```

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/XL8f9/)

Any explanation for this and a solution if this can be done in a easier and cleaner way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to delegate the event for dynamic elements, and make sure the ID is unique

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadpic').on('change', '.choose-file', function (e) {
        $('<input />', {
            type     : 'file',
            multiple : 'multiple',
            id       : 'File' + ($('.choose-file').length + 1),
            'class'  : 'choose-file',
            name     : 'choose-file'
        }).insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3jTrA/3/)

Answer (score 0):

with your code you can do this:

```
function add_input($t) {        
   $t.after('<input type="file" multiple="true" id="File' + $('[type="file"]').length +'" class="choose-file" name="choose-file" />');        
}


$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#uploadpic').on("change", '.choose-file', function(e) {// delegate the event for dynamically added elemnt    
        var $t = $(this);        
        add_input($t);        
    });   
});
```

---

Syntax for event delegation is:

```
$(parent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

here `callback` is the function you want to trigger and `$(parent)` is the closest static parent which was availble when doc was loaded and for delegating the event you can delegate to `$(document), $(document.body)` which is always available but *delegating to document is slow.*

Comment: This has the same behaviour as the problem statement. Try adding a file to the new file input item.